# Rescue, exceptions in Ruby's selenium-webdriver, not to terminate program

Tags: ruby, selenium

I tried finding how to rescue selenium from terminating my program session, however I could not.

It would be great if anybody could give one, or maybe several exceptions to include in a selenium program, for a script not to crash.

To give more details, for example, one case can be that when page load takes too long, then in console application running process terminates and profiled browser keeps on running. I would like a process not to terminate, somehow.

I am sure there are other cases other than load time, program terminates / stops to run for other reasons of selenium I guess and that is what I want to handle.

I would like my program not to exit automatically, but whenever it actually should stop.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running multiple tests and is that when it happens?

Comment: Example is that a page should load data from external website through api and since sometimes it takes a bit longer to connect a program exits.